# iReport: Setting Parameter Values from Query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, ireport

I am fairly new to *JasperReports* and *iReport* and am struggling with something, which seems should be basic.

If you use *MongoDB* then you know it does not support the concept of a 'JOIN'.  Therefore, from the *iReport* main dataset query I want to set a parameter/variable from the results.  Then I want to use the collection values I just set in a different dataset as a query parameter/variable (NOT table, or LIST - just a plain old simple dataset I create, which will also query MongoDB as the source).

It seems this would be a straight forward use case, but I don't see anything intuitive in *iReport* that seems would do this.  Can this be done?  If so any clues you can give me would be wonderful and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have tried to passing the data as a collection to a subreport? Or have to tried passing field values as parameters?

Comment: Subreport doesn't really cut it, only be a minor workaround. The real issue is I can't seem to combine data within Jasper. For  traditional databases it would not be necessary I can perform joins at the database level. Using Mongo, it is a severe limitation because it doesn't support traditional 'join'. Example, if I had three pieces of data in different collections-Data1, Data2, Data3 all with adjoining keys. There is no way to combine results because I can't simply query Data1 and pass a value to Data2. Is there a way for this? I.E.Query a dataset, get a value and pass to another dataset?

Comment: P.S. Also, I realize the other way I could do this is by canonicalizing my documents so they contain all the information at once.  Once could even argue that is the true spirit of big data stores like MongoDB, but I am just wondering why there isn't a way to do what I would like to, i.e. passing info from Mongo query to another

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass the values as collection from one report onto the other ?

This can be done by writing the following in your filter expression `$P{parameter_name}.contains($F{field_name})`. Additionally, you need to create parameter with the same `parameter_name` with class type `java.util.collection` .

Now this report is ready to receive any parameters as collections. This works for MongoDB as I have tried this out. Now as you have already said that you have been able to send the collection from the main report, the above method will work for receiving the parameter in the second report.